# DropDownList reset itself to the first selelected element

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am using two DropDownLists on my webform inside an updatePanel.

Here is the code:

```
  <asp:DropDownList id="HoraireTrie1"
                AutoPostBack="false"
                runat="server">
              <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 00 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 01 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 02 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 03 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 04 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 05 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 06 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 07 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 08 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 09 </asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0"> 10 </asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 11 </asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Value="0">12 </asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 13 </asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 14 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 15 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 16 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 17 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 18 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 19 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 20 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 21 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 22 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 23 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 24 </asp:ListItem>
           </asp:DropDownList>
                 h à
            <asp:DropDownList id="HoraireTrie2"
                AutoPostBack="false"
                runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 00 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 01 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 02 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 03 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 04 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 05 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 06 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 07 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 08 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 09 </asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 10 </asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 11 </asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Value="0">12 </asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 13 </asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 14 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 15 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 16 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 17 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 18 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 19 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 20 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 21 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 22 </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 23 </asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0"> 24 </asp:ListItem>
           </asp:DropDownList>h
                 <br /><br /><br />
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonRechercher" runat="server" 
                CssClass="linkButtonSemaine" OnClick="LinkButton_ChercherHoraire" CommandArgument="Rechercher">
                Rechercher
            </asp:LinkButton>
```

When I click on Rechercher (inside ChercherHoraire function) , for some reason, the two DropDownLists have their SelectedItem to the first element of the list (00). How can I fix this please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because all of your ListItem's values are the same. They should have different values.

You need to omit `Value` attribute on `ListItem`s - then ASP.NET will use ListItem's text as identifier, or set unique values.

```
<asp:DropDownList id="HoraireTrie1"
    AutoPostBack="false"
    runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0"> 00 </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1"> 01 </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1"> 02 </asp:ListItem>
...
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, I thought that Value wasn't important since I am only using the item but I suppose it wasn't the case.